# run multiple select quires in one page using codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Hello any one can tell that how to load two function from model class in controller one method. I want to run multiple select quires in one page using codeigniter:

Controller

```
public function property_detail( $id )
{
    $this->load->model('insertmodel');

    $select1 = $this->insertmodel->find($id);
    $select2 = $this->insertmodel->detail_list();

    $data = array();

    $this->load->view('home/property_detail', ['select1'=>$select1], ['select2'=>$select2]);
    //$this->load->view('home/property_detail', ['select2'=>$select2]);

}
```

Model

```
public function find( $id )
{
    $query = $this->db->from('article')->where(['id'=> $id])->get();
    if( $query->num_rows() )
        return $query->row();
    return false;
}

public function detail_list(){

    $query1 = $this->db->query("select * from article");
    return $query1->result();
}
```

Comment: You should create separate thread for every select query.

Answer (score 1):

**In Controller**

```
public function property_detail( $id )
{
    $this->load->model('insertmodel');

    $data['select1'] = $this->insertmodel->find($id);
    $data['select2'] = $this->insertmodel->detail_list();

    $this->load->view('home/property_detail', $data);
}
```

**In Model**

```
public function find($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('article', array('id' => $id), 0, 0)->get();
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $result =  $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }    
}

public function detail_list()
{
    $query1 = $this->db->query("select * from article");
    $result =  $query1->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

**In View**

```
foreach ($select2 as $item) {
    # your foreach lop goes here
}
```

> > As well check `empty()` before passing it to the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Model :

```
public function find( $id )
{
$query = $this->db->from('article')->where(['id'=> $id])->get();
if( $query->num_rows() )
    return $query->row();
return false;
}
public function detail_list()
{
$query1 = $this->db->query("select * from article");
return $query1->result();
}
```

Controller :

```
public function property_detail( $id )
{
    $this->load->model('insertmodel');

    $data['select1'] = $this->insertmodel->newMethod($id);

    $data['select2'] = $this->insertmodel->detail_list();
    $this->load->view('home/property_detail', $data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @Rijin's useful answer `newMethod()` can make calls to the existing model methods. This might be useful if you don't want to break the interface already created for the model because you are using `find($id)` and `detail_list()` in other code.

Model:

```
public function find($id)
{
  $query = $this->db->from('article')->where(['id' => $id])->get();
  if($query->num_rows())
    return $query->row();
  return false;
}

public function detail_list()
{
  $query1 = $this->db->query("select * from article");
  return $query1->result();
}

public function newMethod($id)
{
  $result['select1'] = $this->find($id);
  if($result['select1'] !== FALSE)
  {
    $result['select2'] = $this->detail_list();
    return $result;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function property_detail($id)
{
  $this->load->model('insertmodel');
  $data = $this->insertmodel->newMethod($id);
  $this->load->view('home/property_detail', $data);
}
```